# Vagrant not working on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vagrant

I have installed Vagrant 1.8.1 on Windows 7. Following documentation, ran these commands:

`vagrant init hashicorp/precise32
vagrant up`

On `vagrant init`, `Vagrantfile` is being generated, but `vagrant up` is failing and I get following output:

`Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
vagrant login. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:
URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/precise32"]
Error:`

Here is error from debug info:

`URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/precise32"]
Error:
 INFO interface: Machine: error-exit ["Vagrant::Errors::BoxAddShortNotFound", "The box 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found or\ncould not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private\nbox on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via\n`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded\nURL and error message are shown below:\n\nURL: [\"https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/precise32\"]\nError: "]`

I have also tried disabling antivirus, but no luck. Then I tried installation on different machine, on that machine also I am getting same error message.

Answer (score 1):

it's answer to issue in vagrant repo helped for me https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6754
short: install http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328